# sigemptyset() is overwriting next variable

Tags: c, signals

I have global variables

```
int a[10];
struct sigaction act;
int b[10];
```

Whenever I call

```
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
```

array `a` is getting corrupted. I doubt if it is compiler issue. I am using CodeSourcery mips-linux-gnu-gcc version 4.5.2. I compile using

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -c -g -muclibc -pedantic -Wno-declaration-after-statement -std=gnu99 -G 0 -mips2 -msoft-float -mno-memcpy -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes signal/signal.c

mips-linux-gnu-gcc -G 0 -msoft-float -static -o signal  signal.o
```

My complete code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
int a[10];
struct sigaction act;
int b[10];


int main ();
int main ()
{
int i;
//initialize a and b
for(i = 0 ; i < 10;i++)
{
    a[i]=1;b[i]=1;
}

sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);

//print
for(i = 0 ; i < 10;i++)
{
    printf("%d %d ",a[i],b[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

**I found that using the `-muclibc` option for compiling causes this issue.**

Comment: Could you include the smallest *complete* example that has this problem?

Comment: Probably your header files are for some other library(e.g. glibc or newlib), and not uClibc , or you've linked in glibc or newlib, but are using the uClibc header files.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the `struct sigaction act` *after* the a array, but in the code you mention a `siginfo` variable, not `act`.

Could `siginfo` be declared *before* the a array ? Could you show what that function is doing ?

Comment: sorry my mistake it is                                               int a[10];
struct sigaction act;
int b[10];

Comment: if i compile my code using `mips-linux-gnu-gcc -static -o signal_  signal/signal.c` then there is no issue, don't know what compiler option is causing the issue

Comment: @user919082: int a[10]; struct sigaction act; int b[10]; is the same code that is in your question. **Could you post a more complete example** to show what is `siginfo` and what `sigemptyset()` is doing ?

Comment: sorry :-(, added complete code now, please see above, any idea why is it causing issue after including `-muclibc`

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer
I am not linking with -muclibc option

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -G 0 -msoft-float -static -muclibc -o signal  signal.o
```

will solve the problem

so while compiling it is is using sigset.h from uclibc and while executing it was 
executing code from libc(`signal.c sigemptyset()`)

and if you digdown further `_SIGSET_NWORDS` for mips is 4 while for x86 it is 32
so `sigemptyset()` was running for 32 iteration instead of 4